# Is there a way to merge return type of an uncertain number of functions in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

[sample code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=91#code/MYewdgzgLgBBAWIDuMC8MAUBKNA%20TA3jFAJ4AOApgFwwBECytMAvlgNwBQoksEFUAFQoAPWOgxQRUGtABOASzABzHKnwYipSjXr8ho2gBoYZAIYkANiFMATGpqksW7Dl3DQYwWRVNQQsiDQYAg4YMLhEJENQ8L5BKQ5mVy0KGABBYCh5cABhb19-CAAeAXx0AQBtAGsKEhAAMxgBAF0YKQowG0CMADo%2001klCBpTMBIK5tV8RXqKWRgAJRgAfkWYGjAKADc5zg4U9KCMrNz8vwCilIbPM8LcTgB6B8P0TXJUmSgFZRYOJ7bhJRMoc-DAAEapN6UdZwL6KJQwYxmSzWGwwhyiGFyeFOJL-ACSgSg8DmqVMMCQ5mIIBgNhpxN8xggimAqS8PnOgW4zI811GMAArmBWbIoKZFDAwAKALYQgIwa71IWZbKQZZAA) 
 Is there a way to do that, since creators consist of an uncertain numbers of functions?

```
    const show = () => ({ type: "show" });
    const setText = (text: string) => ({ type: "setText", payload: { text } });

    const creators = {
        show,
        setText
    }

    type ActionCreators<T> = T[keyof T] extends (...args: any[]) => infer R ? R : never;

    type A = ActionCreators<typeof creators>;
    // A = { type : string }
    // expect A to be { type : string , payload : { text : string } }
    // Is there a way to do that, since creators consist of an uncertain numbers of functions?
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you mean by "merge".  What you're getting is the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) of method return types.  Perhaps you want the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) instead?  You could use a [conditional type trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/2887218) to synthesize an intersection of an unknown number of types; here it is, adapted to pulling out method return types:

```
type IntersectionOfMethodReturnTypes<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: (x: T[K] extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : unknown) => void
}[keyof T] extends ((x: infer R) => void) ? R : never;
```

That produces

```
type A = IntersectionOfMethodReturnTypes<typeof creators>
/*
type A = {
    type: string;
} & {
    type: string;
    payload: {
        text: string;
    };
}
*/
```

which is equivalent to what you want.  If you want it to look explicitly like a single object type you could change the type alias definition slightly:

```
type IntersectionOfMethodReturnTypes<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: (x: T[K] extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : unknown) => void
}[keyof T] extends ((x: infer R) => void) ? { [K in keyof R]: R[K] } : never;
```

which produces

```
/*
type A = {
    type: string;
    payload: {
        text: string;
    };
}
*/
```

This does what I think you want at the type level; whether or not it represents the types of values you actually produce or deal with depends on your implementation.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBBAWIDuMC8MAUBKNA+TA3jFAJ4AOApgFwwBECytMAvlgNwBQoksEFUAFQoAPWOgxQRUGtABOASzABzHKnwYipSjXr8ho2gBoYZAIYkANiFMATGpqksW7Dl3DQYwWRVNQQsiDQYAg4YMLhEJENQ8L5BKWjmVy0KGABJMEkAimAoeXAAeQAzAFl+RBsAJX4AV1kwAXIKCAAeAXx0EPCYAG0AaRhFGABrChIQIpgBAF0aDGEaAX7pmCkKMBtAjAA6XdNZJQgaUzASVXxFIopZGEqYAH5bmBoasGGwZDBzmAA3EHkbBxmD1RuNJjNVqJ1ptMPMaJdrrdvn8AThHkR+oMwCMxhNbrNbssnDQwBQftdOBwUjAAIJBDJZPi5fJgYplKAVapQOoNJqtFJ4rw+PwBXAcAD0ACoqU1aUEuuEUjIoAplJxumZLNY7MEYt0wpJRMrVUp1eFmJwkpLxRwgA)